# Priority of DNS servers

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, process-priority

I actually have 2 DNS providers and 3 DNS server.
The first and is from CloudFlare - primary, and the third is from BuddyNS - this one should be used only for backup.
Backup: the server should be *only* when are primary server unavailable.
Is this realisable? (at .cz)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no mechanism to indicate "priority" of authoritative DNS servers. You could theoretically swap out the nameserver records for your domain at the registrar, but due to various layers of DNS caching, that's not going to be an instantaneous change.

Comment: NOTE: If all your clients are using to these DNSen then you have chance to do what you want by the ordering of the DNS server entries in the clients' /etc/resolv.conf file on UNIX/Linux environment.